# buildbot: connect to IRC server using SSL

Tags: python, ssl, twisted, irc, buildbot

How can I use buildbot's IRC bot to connect to an IRC server that wants SSL connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just submitted a small patch to BuildBot which will allow the IRC bot to connect to SSL-enabled servers.  Should be included in the next release (0.7.12?).

If you want to apply it to your setup, it's a [simple patch](http://github.com/djmitche/buildbot/commit/4412014653749be47026054cbbf4e702abb0ec08) to backport.

Answer (score 1):

You could fix the tunnel on the buildbots localhost with stunnel, for e.g.:

```
 stunnel -c -D5 -r dest.irc.server:port -d 127.0.0.1:6667
```

And then let buildbot connect to 127.0.0.1:6667

Comment: +0 thank you for showing stunnel - interesting stuff in itself.